# Testing components in oidc-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openid-connect

I'm using oidc-react library to authentication and auth flow.
I have to unit testing my components.
How can I inject a user to ?

Answer (score -1):

You should mock the package and return a desired response for the token.

Comment: Answer is a bit too vague, it would help to add some more info on how to mock the package.